# Has anybody been able to fix the RDP authentication error 0x800706be in Windows 11 after upgrading from Windows 10?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I upgraded to Windows 11 pro from a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro (unknown which version) the week that 11 came out. Since then, I am not able to connect to ANY Remote Desktop server. I get an authentication failure message with the error code 0x800706be. A cursory search on google indicates that this seems to only crop up when doing an upgrade vs a fresh install.

I’ve tried sfc and it did find and fix at least one corrupted file but I still can’t use Remote Desktop unless I use the windows store app, which is not great for my use case. I was hoping that I’d see a fix come in on patch Tuesday but I still haven’t.

Here’s an example of the problem: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/516232/error-34an-authentication-error-has-occurred-code.html

> I solved my issue in a radical way, maybe this will help to find a bugfix:
>
> Because it was a new PC with a fresh Win10 installation from Sunday (honestly an old version from 09.2017 which I upgraded to latest possible, in my case 20H2).
>
> Everything was fine, RDP made a good job with the latest Win10 20H2 version.
>
> Two days later I made the Win11 upgrade on Tuesday and the reported error appeared. I just installed a few programms on my Win10: LibreOffice, Tracker PDFeditor and old versions of OneNote (Desktop) and Adobe CS.
>
> Because I found no bugfixes online, I decided to waste no time and go ahead with new installation:
>
> First try: Win11 repair with keeping all personal data > no effect, problem was still the same.
>
> Second try: Complete fresh Win11 installation with formating the HDD > After that and also after installing the same programs, the mstsc.exe RDP programm worked without any problem. EDIT: I forgot, I installed 7zip on Win10 but not after the fresh Win11 installation.
>
> Obviously it a problem with the Update and not with the mstsc.exe or with the account in general. The MS Store RDP client (which is really bad) worked. But this is not really a solution for a full dialy use and if the fullscreen without the task bar of the local system is needed. Hopefully this will not happen again with a later Win11 update.

Comment: RDP works fine here on Windows 11 Pro - Production and Insider both. Did you fully update Windows 11?  Did you ensure Remote Assistance has been enabled?

Comment: If everything looks like RDP should work, or if it was working before the upgrade to Windows 11, redo it with an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) (link is for Windows 10, but should still work with light modifications).

Answer (score 1):

(https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1778270-rdp-from-windows-10-to-anywhere)

The simple fix is to head to
C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack

and change

BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll
to

BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll.BAK

Comment: You are a genius, been struggling with this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when running Remote Desktop elevated as a different user, and that different user account has never logged in to the workstation (no complete local profile).  I've submitted a bug report to Microsoft, please help me get some traction on it with an upvote! https://aka.ms/AAkm0o2